# Lambda expression query for faster execution

Tags: c#

In this lambda query we are doing time conversion that is more expensive how we can optimize this line of code that make faster execution. Is there any work around we can do this conversion before lambda query.

```
ConvertTimeHelper.FromAirportToUTC(x.Scheduled, airportIATA, messageGuid)?.Date == originDate.Date
```

Query :

```
IEnumerable<Flight> flights = cache.GetAllFlights().Where(x =>
                                    x.Linecode.Equals(_flightMessage.lineCode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                                    x.DisplayFlightNumber.Equals(_flightMessage.displayFlightNumber, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                                    ConvertTimeHelper.FromAirportToUTC(x.Scheduled, airportIATA, messageGuid)?.Date == originDate.Date &&
                                    x.ADI == adi.Value);

IEnumerable<Flight> flights = cache.GetAllFlights().Where(x =>
                                    x.Linecode.Equals(_flightMessage.lineCode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                                    x.DisplayFlightNumber.Equals(_flightMessage.displayFlightNumber, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                                    ConvertTimeHelper.FromAirportToUTC(x.Scheduled, airportIATA, messageGuid)?.Date == originDate.Date &&
                                    x.ADI == adi.Value);
```

In this lambda query we are doing time conversion that is more expensive how we can optimize this line of code that make faster execution. Is there any work around we can do this conversion before lambda query.

```
ConvertTimeHelper.FromAirportToUTC(x.Scheduled, airportIATA, messageGuid)?.Date == originDate.Date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `time conversion` before and after that `apply` lambda query on this.

```
var catchflights = cache.GetAllFlights().Select(x=>
                     ConvertTimeHelper.FromAirportToUTC(x.Scheduled, airportIATA, messageGuid)?.Date);
```

Apply lambda query on cacheFlights.